# Android billing v3 - NullPointerException at BillingClientImpl.java:668

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have exception with **Google Play Billing Library** v3.
I release billing client in the **onDestroy** method of activity.

Did anyone have this issue ?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
   at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$BillingServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(BillingClientImpl.java:668)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1259)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1276)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5830)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

The code of billing client connection call:

```
private com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient billingClient;

public AppBillingManager(Context context) {
    billingClient = new BillingClient.Builder(context)
            .setListener(this)
            .build();
}

public void doConnect(final Runnable postConnection) {
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(int resultCode) {
            isConnected = BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK == resultCode;
            notifyConnectivityState();
            if (isConnected) {
                postConnection.run();
            } else {
                listener.onConnectedToBillingService(resultCode);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            isConnected = false;
            listener.onDisconnectedBillingService();
        }
    });
}

public void release() {
    this.billingClient.endConnection();
}
```

Comment: Faced the same issue on low-end devices.

Comment: @pratt did you ever find a solution, I'm facing this now and can't understand where the NPE is coming from

Comment: @spaceman, NPE comes from google billing library. To fix that I've simply added billing-library project as module into my own project and edited BillingClientImpl.java source file. The problem is that calling BillingManager.destroy() (usually in Activity.onDestroy()) calls BillingClientImpl.endConnection() which nullifies internal mContext reference. But under some circumstances you may still  BillingServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() get called after activity death and internally it uses mContext which is already null. You may choose do not nullify mContext or check it for null.

Comment: @spaceman seems that 2 months ago Google released new version of billing library `com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0`. You may give a try. I looked at source code and looks like this issue is fixed now.

Comment: @pratt thanks for getting back to me, I've been getting this crash with version 1.0 so either I'm experiencing a different issue or this issue hasn't been fixed yet, but I'm working on fixing it right now

Answer (score 0):

Google recently released a new version of billing library. Check it out. This should be fixed.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/google-play-billing-library-10-released.html